# How to display blob as image from oracle using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, image, blob, adodb

I'm trying to display an image that is stored as a blob in oracle using PHP. I'm using the adodb library.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
$db=conGenedesa();
    $query ="SELECT * FROM 'TABLE' p WHERE p.ID = $id";
    $result = odbc_exec($db, $query);

    $name;
    $dni;
    $jobID;
    $base;
    while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
        $name = odbc_result($result, 'PER_APELLIDO_PATERNO') . ' ' . odbc_result($result, 'PER_APELLIDO_MATERNO') . ' ' . odbc_result($result, 'PER_NOMBRES');
        $dni = $rut . '-' . odbc_result($result, 'PER_RUT_DV');
        $jobID = odbc_result($result, 'PER_CAR_CODIGO');
        $base = odbc_result($result, 'PER_MOVIL_IMG');
    }

    $src;
    if($base == null){
        echo 'null';
    }
    else{
        $src='data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($base);
    }
?>
<img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" />
```

I know the image is not corrupted, because i can see it from another application using dotnet.

UPDATE:

In the end, PHP was truncating the blobs output. I corrected it inserting this line.

```
ini_set('odbc.defaultlrl', '10M');
```

Comment: So precisely what result do you get then?

Comment: P.s. are you sure you mean adodb? Your code says odbc.

Comment: I get a broken base64 string, so the image shows as broken.

It is ADOdb, from http://adodb.sourceforge.net. I didn't pick the library, was already there in the project

Answer (score 0):

Although it's for OCI8 not ADOdb, the section "Uploading and Displaying an Image" on page 236 of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) may have some helpful clues.

Since you seem to have fetched your data OK, your question isn't really an Oracle one, so plenty of other resource can be used.